# Component not rendering when I add something

Tags: vue.js

I have just added a router link top my component. The idea is that when user clicks this button it goes to the `post` view in my router file.

Component where I have my router-link:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <h2 class="mt-32 flex justify-center text-3xl ">The Happy Algorithm</h2>
    <div class="ml-10 flex flex-row">
      <div class="ml-64">
        <a href=""
          ><img class=" mt-8 pt-32 " src="../assets/study-work.png" alt=""
        /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="pl-32 pr-32 p-20 mt-8 ml-10 mr-64">
        <h2>Working and Studying Full - Time - What the heck?</h2>
        <p class="text-justify text-sm pt-6">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
          reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
          culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'Post', params: { id: post.id } }">
          <button class="read-more">Read more about this</button>
        </router-link>
        <router-view />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "LatestPost",
};
</script>
```

My view:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div v-for="descricao in post" :key="descricao">
      <h3>{{ post.descricao }}</h3>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { api } from "@/../services.js";
export default {
  name: "Post",
  props: ["id"],
  data() {
    return {
      post: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getPost() {
      api.get(`/post/${this.id}`).then(response => {
        this.post = response.data;
        console.log(this.post);
      });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getPost();
  },
};
</script>
```

My router file:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router, { RouteConfig } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import Podcasts from "../views/Podcasts.vue";
import Post from "../views/Post.vue";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: "/podcasts",
      name: "podcasts",
      component: Podcasts,
    },
    {
      path: "/post/:id",
      name: "post",
      component: Post,
      props: true,
    },
  ],
});
```

Getting a few errors in vue:
`Missing required prop: "to"`
`Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '_normalized' of undefined"`
`Property or method "post" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render`
`Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"`

Comment: Does post exists in first component?

Comment: name is case sensitive, so make sure you're calling the route {name: 'post'} instead of {name: 'Post'}

Comment: @Excalibaard done so but still not working!

Comment: @FedericoProvenziani no - the idea is that when clicking the button takes you to the post component.

Comment: If it doesn't exist is pretty normal that you get an error, in fact your link says :to="{ name: 'Post', params: { id: post.id } }.

Comment: @FedericoProvenziani the component where I have my router-link is supposed to take the user to the Post.vue component. I do not need that component to be within the component above.

Comment: I wasn't saying that. I am saying that you're navigating to Post component passing "post.id" as param. But i guess that there "post" is not defined. I see it in component too (no data or whatever), plus the error is saying it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

The button is capturing the click event, so it doesn't propagate to the surrounding router link (which generates a normal anchor (`<a>`).

[Here's an article about distinguishing between links and buttons.](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-links-and-buttons/) The TL;DR is as follows:

> - Are you giving a user a way to go to another page or a different part of the same page? Use a link (`<a href="/somewhere">link</a>`)
> - Are you making a JavaScript-powered clickable action? Use a button (`<button type="button">button</button>`)
> - Are you submitting a form? Use a submit input (`<input type="submit" value="Submit">`)

If you want to [programmatically](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) cause a router action (e.g. by clicking the button, you cause an action), the preferred way is to bind that action to the click event of the button, **instead of using the router-link component**:

```
<button @click="$router.push({ name: 'Post', params: { id: post.id } })
```

If you want to redirect to another page as if the user was clicking a hyperlink, you can style the router link component directly with any classes or adding 'simple elements' (like `<div>` and `<span>`) inside it to get the markup you need.

It's advised not to mix the two approaches for the same use case. In this case, I think the Button is more appropriate. If you want to switch to another view via your navigation, a router-link would be better.